# Metadata injection on JSON input

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm creating a job that takes the inputs of a json input from a table and i'm trying to do a etl metadata injection, i tried with v5.4,v6.0 but non is working.
Is there any work around for my scenario?

Comment: you have to be a lot more specific than that. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: I'm trying to parse a JSON string, for which i could use JSON input in pentaho kettle, The catch is that i have 10-15 different JSON's where in i know all the path, so what i'm doing is i'm maintaining a table with JSON_Name,Column_Name,Path and i thought of injecting this metadata with ETL Metadata injection. But it seems we couldn't use ETL metadata injection with JSON input, Is there any work around.? Clear?

Comment: which PDI version? Paste the logs of the transformation. JSON input allows metadata injection, but I'm not sure if it's only on PDI 7 or if it's there from an earlier version.

Comment: i have used 5.4,6.1,7 nothing works

Comment: JSON input supports metadata injection, at least on version 7. Without giving more information about your error I don't think anybody can help you.